# SOAPUI picking up values from JDBC response into an array for assert

Tags: xml, soap, groovy, soapui

I have spent a couple of hours on this and after reading some articles I'm unsure if I'm taking the right approach. More on that question at the end.

In my [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46459809/soapui-square-brackets-around-my-actual-results-causing-assert-to-fail) it was found that I was using an array when I shouldn't have been. My latest problem is the reverse of this in that I want to grab data from my jdbc response into an array to assert against a SOAP response which is also in an array.

I have the actual (EDITED) results from the SOAP response in array form working fine but the JDBC response is only grabbing the first value so assert fails.

Here is a snip from my JDBC response:

```
<Results>
    <ResultSet fetchSize="64">
        <Row rowNumber="1">
            <TW070_VALIDATION.CODE>APP</TW070_VALIDATION.CODE>
            <TW070_VALIDATION.VALID_DATA/>
        </Row>
        <Row rowNumber="2">
            <TW070_VALIDATION.CODE>CHI</TW070_VALIDATION.CODE>
            <TW070_VALIDATION.VALID_DATA>1</TW070_VALIDATION.VALID_DATA>
        </Row>
        <Row rowNumber="3">
            <TW070_VALIDATION.CODE>DEN</TW070_VALIDATION.CODE>
            <TW070_VALIDATION.VALID_DATA>1</TW070_VALIDATION.VALID_DATA>
        </Row>
   </ResultSet>
</Results>
```

I would like to pick up both values for each row returned. So in this example I am looking to get the following picked up to use for my expected result:

APP= ,CHI=1,DEN=1

My assert script currently looks like this:

```
def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils( context )
def holder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder( messageExchange.responseContent )
def pxml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(context.response)

//grab the expected result from jdbc response
def expectedCodes = context.expand( '${JDBC Request for expected results#ResponseAsXml#//*:TW070_VALIDATION.CODE}' ) 

//grab the actual result from the SOAP response
def actualCodes = pxml.'**'.findAll{it.name() == 'ReportAssessment'}.collectEntries{[(it.ReportAssessmentGroup.text()):it.Ranking.text()]}

log.info expectedCodes
log.info actualCodes

assert expectedCodes == actualCodes
```

EDIT: Adding in a picture of my test structure.[image]

EDIT2: Adding in a sample from my SOAP response (Step 4)

```
             <ns2:ReportAssessment>
                <ns2:ReportAssessmentGroup>APP</ns2:ReportAssessmentGroup>
                <ns2:Ranking>0</ns2:Ranking>
                <ns2:ReportAssessmentGroupDescription>APPLIANCES</ns2:ReportAssessmentGroupDescription>
             </ns2:ReportAssessment>
             <ns2:ReportAssessment>
                <ns2:ReportAssessmentGroup>CHI</ns2:ReportAssessmentGroup>
                <ns2:Ranking>1</ns2:Ranking>
                <ns2:ReportAssessmentGroupDescription>CHIROPRACTIC</ns2:ReportAssessmentGroupDescription>
             </ns2:ReportAssessment>
             <ns2:ReportAssessment>
                <ns2:ReportAssessmentGroup>DEN</ns2:ReportAssessmentGroup>
                <ns2:Ranking>1</ns2:Ranking>
                <ns2:ReportAssessmentGroupDescription>DENTAL</ns2:ReportAssessmentGroupDescription>
```

I have been reading about loop approaches so unsure if I can address this in the groovy script or if I need a different test structure to contain a loop.

Comment: Matt, you can check the solution below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

It appears that, you have an issue becuase the element name has `.`. So, it needs to be enclosed between the quotes as shown below:

First find all `Rows` and create map out of each row.

Here is the `Script Assertion`

```
//Define the expected map (key value pairs)
def expected = [APP: '', CHI: '1', DEN: '1']

//Read the xml and create map
def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(context.response)
def actual = xml.'**'.findAll{it.name() == 'Row'}.collectEntries{ [(it.'TW070_VALIDATION.CODE'.text()): it.'TW070_VALIDATION.VALID_DATA'.text() ]}
log.info actual
assert expected == actual
```

EDIT: based on the OP comments and chat

```
def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils( context )
def holder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder( messageExchange.responseContent )
def pxml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(context.response)

//grab the expected result from jdbc response
def jdbcResponse = context.expand( '${JDBC Request for expected results#ResponseAsXml}')
def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(jdbcResponse)
def expectedCodes = xml.'**'.findAll{it.name() == 'Row'}.collectEntries{ [(it.'TW070_VALIDATION.CODE'.text()):it.'TW070_VALIDATION.VALID_DATA'.text() ]}

//grab the actual result from the SOAP response
def actualCodes = pxml.'**'.findAll{it.name() == 'ReportAssessment'}.collectEntries{[(it.ReportAssessmentGroup.text()):it.Ranking.text()]}

log.info expectedCodes
log.info actualCodes

assert expectedCodes == actualCodes
```

You can quickly try the online <kbd>[demo](https://ideone.com/rlJOy2)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks Rao. I may have not explained this one right. I don't want to hard code any expected results into my assertion here. I want the expected results to be picked up from the JDBC response.

Comment: sorry still not clear. if you see above, values are picked up from jdbc response only and calling them actual. isn't it?

Comment: The assert script is on a SOAP request step. The expected results for this assert are to be grabbed from the JDBC response in a previous step. The actual results are taken from the SOAP response.

Comment: There you are. You wanted to build expected result from request. Right? Then you need to show the request

Comment: I have pasted in an image to show test structure. The assert script in the original post above is attached to that last step - the SOAP request. The assert is needing to grab expected results from the response of step 'JDBC Request for expected results'. This response is pasted above in original post. The actual results will come from the response of the SOAP request step that the assert is attached to.

Comment: Sorry, but really unclear where (step number)to pick the expected results and compare against response (which step number) Please make it simple by providing the data directly, then later you make it to your case.

Comment: Ha, we'l get there! Step number 1 contains the expected result. While step number 4 contains the actual result. This info is in responses to each of these steps. In case it's confusing, Step 2 is grabbing the information that goes into the request of Step 4.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155737/discussion-between-rao-and-matt).